# How to raise an event on other instances of the same class

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime

I have a class with an EventHandler for TimeChanged. A couple of instances of this class are created. In one of the instances of the class, the time can be changed. I would like all instances to react to the event of changed time.

Example:

```
public class MainClass
{

    public MainClass()
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler TimeChanged;

    private virtual void OnTimeChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = TimeChanged;
        if(handler != null) 
        {
            handler(this, eventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass()
    {
       MainClass _mainClass = new MainClass();
    }

    private void OnLoaded()
    {
        _mainClass.TimeChanged += HandleTimeChanged;
    }

    private void HandleTimeChanged
    {
        //Some stuff happens with new time, etc.
    }

}

public class TimeClass
{
    MainClass _class = new MainClass();

    TimeSpan _timeValue;

    private void ChangeTime()
    {
        // This is where the _timeValue is changed
        // All instances of MainClass, subscribed to TimeChanged event to be notified with the new value selected.
    }

}
```

So, basically when I change the time in TimeClass, which contains an instance of MainClass, I want to fire the TimeChanged event and all instances of MainClass (like in AnotherClass) should respond to the TimeChanged event to which they subscribed.

Hope this explains the situation. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: where is Time property that is changed? is it part of the MainClass? or its inside  TimeClass
 ? show it please

Comment: Time property is in the TimeClass. After the change of this _timeValue, I want to notify all instances of MainClass with the new value.

Comment: Change the MainClass so that all instances respond to a shared static event. You can then raise that static event in TimeClass, and then have each MainClass instance respond to that event by raising their instance event.

Comment: @Raymond - is it possible to do this without using a static event?

Comment: using static event is quick dirty solution @RaymondChen but its unclear what you are trying so its hard to give good solution

Comment: I want to change the time value in the TimeClass, and using the TimeClass' instance of MainClass, I want to notify MainClass and all of its instances (like AnotherClass, subscribed to TimeChanged event) that the time has been changed with a new value.

Comment: At the end of the day *somebody* needs to keep track of the instances. You can do it explicitly with a static collection, you can do it explicitly with a MainClassFactory class which hands out MainClass instances (rather than letting people "new" one up) and keeps track of the ones it hands out. Or you can do it implicitly by letting the static event's subscriber list keep track of all the instances. But the answer is the same: Somebody needs to keep track of the instances. There is no magic way to find all instances. (That would be, among other things, a potential security issue.)

Comment: Looks like MainClass should be a Singleton